# Parent div CSS classes are not getting added to child div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a working dropdown with proper CSS classes and it works as expected. In another html page I have copied the same div structures including the CSS classes but it doesn't work.
I am using Chrome browser and When I do the F12 - inspect, I notice that the parent div class are not getting prefixed, and also the right CSS classes are not getting referenced.

Please find the snapshots which compares both with F12 - Inspect details
[image]

[image: F12 Inspect Details]

HTML code for the dropdown which works correctly

```
<div class="application-list">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="applicationMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            {{selected.application}}<span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="applicationMenu">
            <li *ngFor="let app of applications">
                <a (click)=onChange(app)>{{app.application}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

My HTML code for the dropdown which doesn't works correctly

```
<div class="col-lg-7">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <div class="application-list">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="applicationMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                        {{selected.name}}<span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="applicationMenu">
                        <li *ngFor="let app of workbookSheetsList">
                            <a (click)=onChange(app)>{{app.name}}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the mistake I am doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I just discovered a small, but essential detail:

The CSS selector in the first image starts with `application-list..."` - WITHOUT a leading dot, which applies to the `<application-list>` tag, but not for the *class* `.application-list...`.

In your first example there actually IS a tag `<application-list>` in the HTML, in the second example there is a `div` tag with the *class* `application-list`- so the selector `application-list..` in your first example will only apply to the *tag*, not to the *class*  with that name.

To fix it, either insert a wrapping tag `<application-list>` into the HTML of the second page or change the selector of that CSS rule to '.application-list...` (*including* the dot) – the class is present in both examples, the tag only in the first one.

Comment: Please compare my working code with not working in my question, there is no CSS rule selector being added, still it works fine in one place but not in another. why is it behaving differently? what is it I am missing here?

Comment: Are you saying that both are referring to 2 different CSS files? but in my application both are referring to the same files/styles

Comment: It worked finally, created new CSS classes .application-list. The problem was existing CSS classes were not having "." prefix. I have a angular2 component with "application-list" and the existing css classes were referred to that. After creating new ".application-list" CSS classes worked. Thanks for your help :)